# Skip a spec file on fail and still report it as failed on result

Tags: cypress

I am aiming to skip a spec files once an `it()` inside it **fails**. And I would still like to see the error reported so I know where to focus on.

I have two test scripts that is inside the same folder **first.cy.js** and **second.cy.js**:

```js
describe('test body', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        if (cy.state('test').state == 'failed') {
          Cypress.runner.stop()
        }
    })

    it('should pass first test', function() {
        expect(true).to.eq(true)
    })

    it('should pass second test', function() {
        expect(true).to.eq(true)
    })

    it('should fail third test and skip this script', function() {
        expect(true).to.eq(false)
    })

    it('should skip fourth test', function() {
        expect(true).to.eq(true)
    })
})
```

My problem is on result reporting, it does not report the failing part:
[image]

Is there anything I am missing here?

EDIT: I also need to mention that we have retries set on cypress config:

```json
retries: {
    runMode: 2
},
```

Update: Was able to figure out how I will skip the spec file and still record errors with the help of Alapan das:

```js
describe('skipping with retrying and recording', () => {
    let errorCount = 0

    afterEach(() => {
        if (cy.state('test').state == 'failed') {
            errorCount += 1
            if (errorCount == 3) {
                Cypress.runner.stop()

                cy.state('test').state = 'failed'
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `afterEach()` is too early to call `Cypress.runner.stop()`, but it seems to work with `test:after:run`.

```js
describe('test body', () => {

  Cypress.on('test:after:run', (result) => {
    if (result.currentRetry === result.retries && result.state === 'failed') {
      Cypress.runner.stop()
    }
  })

  it('should pass first test', function() {
    expect(true).to.eq(true)
  })

  it('should pass second test', function() {
    expect(true).to.eq(true)
  })

  it('should fail third test and skip this script', function() {
    expect(true).to.eq(false)
  })

  it('should skip fourth test', function() {
    expect(true).to.eq(true)
  })
})
```

---

#### Running two identical tests in a single run

**Before adding the Cypress.on('test:after:run')**

[image]

**After adding the Cypress.on('test:after:run')**

[image]

Comment: I tried adding `on('test:after:run', (result) => {}` to cypress config, `test:after:run` seems to not be recognized as valid event, so I tried `after:run`. The problem that I seem to face it that on issue fail, Cypress does not skip the preceeding `it()`

Comment: Ithink that might be old syntax - I threw it in and the correct result came back (1 failed) but commenting it out, I still get the same correct result. I'm beginning to suspect that the two specs has an effect (i only run one spec). What do you get when running only one spec?

Comment: Can verify `test:after:run` is in the current Cypress build, I think I got it from one of Gleb Bahmutov's blogs. - also on [Cypress events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Cypress-Events).

Comment: are you using `test:after:run` in your cypress config file? inside `setupNodeEvents` to be specific?

Comment: No it's not a node event, it's a browser event use exactly as above in both files or in `cypress/support/e2e.js` to apply to all specs (presuming you want the effect on all specs).

Comment: That's definitely cleaner, most of my scripts are sequential e2e tests, sot this really helps. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran your test exactly in my local with cypress version 10.0.3, I am getting the failure count. This is without test re-tries.

```js
describe('test body', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        if (cy.state('test').state == 'failed') {
            Cypress.runner.stop()
        }
    })

    it('should pass first test', function () {
        expect(true).to.eq(true)
    })

    it('should pass second test', function () {
        expect(true).to.eq(true)
    })

    it('should fail third test and skip this script', function () {
        expect(true).to.eq(false)
    })

    it('should skip fourth test', function () {
        expect(true).to.eq(true)
    })
})
```

Terminal Screenshot:

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

In case of test retries, one way would be to manually set the test state to failed like this:

```js
afterEach(() => {
  if (cy.state('test').state == 'failed') {
    Cypress.runner.stop()
    cy.state('test').state = 'failed'
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, might there be a way to record the fails even if retries are still set?

Comment: I have tried manually setting the state to fail but for some reason, it still does not count as failed. Result were Passing: 2 | Skipped: 2

Comment: For me if I set the retries globally and do like this, I was getting 1 test as failing and 1 test as skipping

Comment: Used your idea and updated my post